# How to import type or interface from other library in namespace at '.d.ts' file?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-typings, typescript3.0, .d.ts

I'm making TypeScript library which is using AWS SDK at work, there is an error in .d.ts file.

`'MyLib' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here. ts(2702)`

I'm using typescript@3.2.4, assign `types/` to typeRoots at `tsconfig.json`.
I tried moving `import` into namespace definition, but it's not solved.

`types/src/lib/mylib.d.ts`

```js
import { S3 } from "aws-sdk";

declare namespace MyLib {
  type DataType = S3.Body;
  class MyLib { }
}
```

`src/lib/mylib.ts`

```js
export default class MyLib {
  constructor(data_type: MyLib.DataType) { }
  //                     ^^^^^ There is a that error here.
}
```

I expected no error that code.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. To do that, make an answer post below, containing an explanation of how you solved it. This may be useful to future readers. You can then click the tick/check symbol to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

AWS SDK exported namespace as `AWS`, so I can use like `AWS.S3`.

`types/src/lib/mylib.d.ts`

```js
declare namespace MyLib {
  type DataType = AWS.S3.Body;
  class MyLib { }
}
```